# How to put navigation bar or something above XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I'm new to iOS programming and got stuck using XLPagerTabStrip(github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip).
I followed its tutorial and successfully added PagerTab on the top of VC.
However, I can't add something like navbar on the top of VC, above the PagerTab. The PagerTab always go to the top even though I set layouts using storyboard. The tutorial doesn't help me, and there are similar questions in github issues and this website, but I can't find answer to my problem. I'd appreciate it if you teach me how to solve it.

[My storybord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoHX9.jpg) 
[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNAwS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As refer to your storyboard, you have not added the `UINavigationbarController`.

1. Select the ViewController in storyboard.
2. On Xcode menu, select Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller
3. Run and check

This issue not relate to XLPagerTabStrip, it is UINavigationController itself. Refer [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1) for details.

Comment: Sorry, in the image I used UIView to make it clear.
The same problem occurs even if it is UINavigationbar or other Views.